# How to redirect to a certain URL on a click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, click

Once you click on a button it opens a video. I would like to redirect a user to another URL once they clicked to close the video. 
I am not familiar with JavaScript code, so I have no idea how to do it:)

```
function playVideo () {
    $('#play').click(function () {
        var video = $('#final-video');
        video.css({
            opacity: 1,
            pointerEvents: 'auto'
        })

        video[0].play();

        video.click(function () {
            $(this).css({
                opacity: 0,
                pointerEvents: 'none',
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: On `video` click you want o redirect instead of just hiding it?

Comment: Yes tha'ts what I want do do

Answer (score 0):

On your close video event, you can simply add one of these lines of code to redirect to another url.

To redirect to another page, you can use:

```
window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

or

```
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use `location.href`.

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`.

To redirect in a new tab

```
window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I don't know how to add it unto my code. I juste pasted it inside, but it didn't work. Could you show me how to do it right ?

  video.click(function () {
   $(this).css({
    opacity: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
   })
  })
 })
}

Comment: HTML 
```<video id="final-video" src="images/Video_02.mp4"></video>```

CSS
```#final-video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000000;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}```
And what I tried to do:
  
  ```video.click(function () {
   $(this).css({
    opacity: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
    window.location('http://stackoverflow.com');
   })
  })
 })
}```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can also do this in html:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">Your text here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function playVideo () {
    $('#play').click(function () {
        var video = $('#final-video');
        video.css({
            opacity: 1,
            pointerEvents: 'auto'
        })

        video[0].play();

        video.click(function () {
           /* This event fires, when video is loaded and
              user clicked it. Here you can do your redirect
              instead of what's being done here */
            $(this).css({
                opacity: 0,
                pointerEvents: 'none',
            })
        })
    })
}
```

So it can be like this:

```js
function playVideo () {
    $('#play').click(function () {
        var video = $('#final-video');
        video.css({
            opacity: 1,
            pointerEvents: 'auto'
        })

        video[0].play();

        video.click(function () {
            window.location('http://stackoverflow.com');
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Now I can't get out of the video and the link still doesn't work.

Comment: I would really appreciate some demonstration of your problem with proper HTML ad JS to see what's really happening.

Comment: Of course ! I am new and I don't understand how to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function playVideo () {
 $('#play').click(function () {
  var video = $('#final-video');
  video.css({
   opacity: 1,
   pointerEvents: 'auto'
  })

  video[0].play();

  video.click(function () {
   $(this).css({
    opacity: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
   })
  })
 })
}
```

```css
#final-video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000000;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
  <video id="final-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3rXoJdu_Ek
"></video>

  <div id="play" class="section-gameplay">
      <button class="button-start" id="button-start2" data-target="flag-part6">You're ready to play</button>
     </div>
```